# How To Post Notification As Application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, request, facebook-php-sdk

How to post a notification to users as application using facebook php sdk?

I have attached an image, in that picture we can see application from SongPop post a notification to me. I want to make something like this. I think this app post notification to their users, can I post a notification to a spesific user?

[image: notification from application]

Comment: try  to listed links https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

you have to a canvas page url set to in your app config then try with this code

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/notifications";
$notification_message = 'My Example Notification Message';
$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;
$attachment = array(
 'access_token' => $app_access_token, // access_token is a combination of the AppID & AppSecret combined
 'href' => '', // Link within your Facebook App to be displayed when a user click on the notification
 'template' => $notification_message, // Message to be displayed within the notification
   );
// set the target url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```